# How does opengl32.lib work on windows(just version 1.1)? Does it actually implements OpenGL functions?

Tags: c++, opengl

i am little bit confused how does opengl32.lib library work - without any extensions for opengl version bigger than 1.1. 
Does opengl32 lib implement OpenGL 1.1 functions, or just it's retrieving them from graphic driver as new OpenGL functions? If yes, shouldn't GPU vendors implement OpenGL? Does the opengl32 lib work like a part of graphic driver that implements OpenGL? If I won't have graphic driver installed, will opengl32 work(just the base v. 1.1 of course)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago, those of OpenGL 1.1, `opengl32.dll` provided all gl-functions needed. When newer versions came in scene it was also the case that vendors implemented "extensions" functions to standard functions. And there was also the case where two different graphics cards may be installed at once. If all of this should be handled by the OS, then man, what a nightmare!

The solution was that each vendor provides his driver, for example Nvidia's `nvoglv32.dll`. Now `opengl32.dll` looks in Windows’ system registry and if it finds a vendor driver loads it and let it handles the gl-stuff. If there's not a vendor implementation then `opengl32.dll` handles gl-stuff, but only for OGL version 1.1.

`opengl32.lib` (not .dll) is a linker symbol stub. It says that `opengl32.dll` is needed by the executable.

`opengl32.a` is the same as `opengl32.lib`. The `.lib` is provided by MS VS and the `.a` is provided by MingGW.